# how to convert data of 536 files into excel having 536 columns using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 536 files in fasta format. each file has 5000 records. I have extracted all the records from the 536 files using python. Now I have to convert this data into excel so that each file name appears as a heading in the excel and each heading has its own records

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = [10,20]
list2 = [40,30]
col1 = "X"
col2 = "Y"
data = pd.DataFrame({col1:list1,col2:list2})
data.to_excel('sample_data.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

this can not be done manually. I need help in automating this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you extracted the records already I assume you have the list of file names (here `files`) and the data (here combined in `record_list`) available.

```
files = ['file1', 'file2']
record_list = [[10, 20], [30, 40]]
data_dict = {file: record  for file, record in zip(files, record_list)} # combines file_name and corresponding record in a dict
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
data.to_excel('sample_data.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: i have data in the below format

Comment: i have the result as below. i have 536 files. each file has around 5000 records like below. all i want is to import this data in excel. excel should have 536 columns. each column name is the file name and each column has all the records respective to that file.

Comment: WP_012510043
WP_012511439
WP_012510641
WP_012511817
WP_006390041
WP_157628479
WP_006401061
WP_012511725
WP_012509979
WP_006390153
WP_004134677
WP_012510829
WP_012510151
WP_012510607
WP_006381058

Comment: You wrote that you have the records already extracted. In what kind of frmat/data structure? In principle you only have to put it into aboves ```record_list``` and ```files``` and would be done. So where exactly is the problem?